# Nginx reverse Proxy - http post - urlencoded content type

Tags: nginx, http-headers, webserver, reverse-proxy

How to consume a http post request via nginx reverse proxy ? the post request content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, is there any idea to pass this through the proxy to my backend application server ? everything is working fine except this.

the below snippet is the sample

```
**#### << Headers >> ####
Connection: Keep-Alive
Expect: 100-continue
Host: your.url.com
Content-Length: 40
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
**#### << Content >> ####****
```

tried providing the content type in the proxy header still not working.